# WPF: MVVM Create custom dependency property for devExpress Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, devexpress

I know you can create custom controls and dependency property for wpf controls like expained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx, I want to know if you can create custom dependency property in the same way for devExpress Controls ? and how ?

There is no way to bind multiple items in comboxBoxEdit control. I want to create a dependency property called SelectedItems on ComboBoxEdit.

I already created a custom property on normal ComboBox called SelectedEnumeration which binds directy to the enums and gets the value. No need to use ObjectDataProvider.

Comment: Of course you can - you just specify the type that the DP belongs to (in the example you gave it would be `typeof(WhateverDxControl)` instead of `typeof(AquariumObject)`. There is also a few examples of multi select AP/DP's floating around for the regular WPF  listbox, you should be able to adapt one of those.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no way to bind multiple items in comboxBoxEdit control.

Wrong. Check [`DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.CheckedComboBoxStyleSettings`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/clsDevExpressXpfEditorsCheckedComboBoxStyleSettingstopic)

Basically, you can bind `ComboBoxEdit.EditValue` to a collection, which gets populated with the selected items.

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
                  EditValue="{Binding SelectedItems}">
    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
        <dxe:CheckedComboBoxStyleSettings />
    </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
</dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyItems {get;set;}

    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> SelectedItems {get;set;}
}
```

---

> I already created a custom property on normal ComboBox called
>   SelectedEnumeration which binds directy to the enums and gets the
>   value. No need to use ObjectDataProvider.

You're putting too much responsibility on the UI, where it does not belong. Create a proper ViewModel and have your data processed by the ViewModel in such a way that it facilitates regular DataBinding to the UI. Don't resort to reflection and other types of uneeded hacks in order to put logic in the wrong layer.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So, I should avoid any custom UI elements right ? I was already doing that. I just thought it would be easy to create custom properties and use it.

Comment: @SoftDev there are times that you need to create custom UI elements, but that's only the case when new UI-specific features are needed. What you're talking about here is interaction with Data, which should really occur at the ViewModel, not the UI.

Comment: I did the same thing you explained above it loads the data my items are enums so, I used ObjectDataProvider it populates it but do not set selecteditems and gives me an error saying . value 'system.collections.generic.list[System.Object]' could not be converted.

Comment: @SoftDev remove the ObjectDataProvider. I have no idea what that is but you don't need it. Also, I think you need a dummy converter. Check on DevExpress support for the correct way to do this.

Comment: I think you havent worked with binding enumerations yet. You have to use ObjectDataProvider to get the enum values and bind that to control.  Take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613576.aspx

Comment: @SoftDev Wrong. Handle that at the ViewModel level.